# WSL - Julia Programming Environment?

Tags: julia, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using WSL on Windows 10 using Arch Linux (Vineel Sai - https://github.com/VSWSL/Arch-WSL)

I'm trying to learn how WSL is managing my environment when using Julia. In my Arch directory is a directory named '.julia' that was created when I installed Julia (using snapd). Is this .julia directory my environment? I ask because when creating a new Julia package it is immediately placed within this directory, regardless of the directory I'm in when creating it.

To create a new Julia package requires moving between the WSL terminal and the Julia REPL several times. I begin with the Arch terminal and the commands 'using PkgTemplates' and then 'generate()' - when the package is created, a new dir named 'dev' is created within the .julia dir and the new pkg is placed there: (.julia /dev). I can easily move the package later, but since I'm in the virtual WSL environment to begin with and also moving in and out of the Julia REPL, I need to understand how both WSL and Julia are determining and managing my environment.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly, but mostly. In Julia an environment has a very specific meaning, it is a folder with a `Project.toml` and a `Manifest.toml` file that list the packages that define the specific environment. The default environment is `.julia/environments/vX.Y/` where X and Y are your julia version, but you can easily create an environmwnt for any project you work with.
When developing a package, each package has its own environment that defines the packages it depends from.

As you have noticed, "in development" packages are set into `.julia/dev` folder, and more in general all pqckages you use are in some subfolder of `.julia`. This will guarantee that when in your pc you will have 1000 projects that use the same version of `Plots.jl`, only one copy of them is stored.

You can chenge these folders with environmental variables, but perhaps the simplest thing if you want to use other locations is to use symlinks (at least within linux)

Comment: That makes sense - every time I created a package it appeared to create a new 'environment' for it along with the .toml and manifest files. And I can see the installed pkgs and environments directories in .julia. directory. I'm too new here to vote up your answer, but it helped clarify - thanks.

Comment: See also my tutorial on developing Julia packages: https://syl1.gitbook.io/julia-language-a-concise-tutorial/language-core/11-developing-julia-packages

Comment: Antonello - Thanks - this will be a very beneficial resource for me.